# Schizophrenic claims are inaccessible to the action, get wiped by the action, but if set by the action can be viewable in the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, claims

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 6

I am experiencing something I have never experienced before.

I can set a claim in one action, but when the user is redirected to another action that claim no longer exists.

I can set a claim within an action that presents a view, and when that view gets viewed I can pull that claim out right into the view.

On that same action, if I pull the claim out into a ViewBag, the claim itself gets nullified -- nothing gets passed to the view, and the claim call in the view also suddenly gets nullified as well.

This is code that I have used across FOUR DIFFERENT MAJOR PROJECTS so far, and I am utterly baffled as to where I am going wrong. Or how.

Here are my two actions for the index page:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
  using(_db = new ApplicationDbContext()) {
    IList<SelectMachineViewModel> data = await _db.Machines.Select(x => new SelectMachineViewModel { MachineId = x.MachineId, MachineName = x.MachineName }).ToListAsync();
    var model = new MachineSelectionViewModel {
      SelectedMachine = string.Empty,
      SelectMachine = new SelectList(data, "MachineId", "MachineName")
    };
    return View(model);
  }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(MachineSelectionViewModel model) {
  var id = model.SelectedMachine;
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id)) {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }
  User.AddUpdateClaim("Machine", id);
  return RedirectToAction("Machine", "Home");
}
```

Looks normal, right? Select an ID from the drop down menu, if it is not null or empty, add it to a claim and then redirect to another page.

And that other page:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Machine() {
  var machineId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.GetClaimValue("Machine")) ? Guid.Empty : new Guid(User.GetClaimValue("Machine"));
  if(machineId == Guid.Empty) { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); }
  ViewBag.Claim = User.GetClaimValue("Machine");
  using(_db = new ApplicationDbContext()) {
    var data = await _db.Machines.Where(x => x.MachineId == id).Include(x => x.MachineImages).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    var model = new MachinePageViewModel() {
      MachineName = data.MachineName,
      MachineDetails = data.MachineDetails,
      MachineImages = new List<MachineImages>()
    };
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

Simple, simple logic: If the claim does not exist, boot the user back to index.

Problem is, THE CLAIM NEVER EXISTS. The user is *always* booted back to the main page. Even when I try to access the claim in the View:

```
Claim: @User.GetClaimValue("Machine")
```

it doesn’t show up at all. Now, if I pass through the ID as a GET variable to this second page:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Machine(Guid? id) {
  User.AddUpdateClaim("Machine", id.ToString());
```

and have a look at the view:

```
Claim: @User.GetClaimValue("Machine")
```

The claim comes through just fine in the view. It shows up on the page perfectly. So claims WORK *within* an action. They just don’t seem to be persisting *between* actions, and I have absolutely no clue why. It’s not a browser thing, tried this across five different browsers on two platforms.

This is an absolute bare-bones test project (to try out some other things) with zero additional stuff set up. All code I am using up until now has been cut-pasted from other projects, so I *know* it should be functional, it just isn’t.

FYI, here are my “extensions” that allow me to get and set claims:

```
public static class Extensions {
  public static void AddUpdateClaim(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, string key, string value) {
    var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if(identity == null) { return; }
    // check for existing claim and remove it
    var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst(key);
    if(existingClaim != null) {
      identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);
    }
    // add new claim
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(key, value));
    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
  }

  public static string GetClaimValue(this IPrincipal currentPrincipal, string key) {
    var identity = currentPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    return identity?.FindFirst(key) != null ? identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == key).Value : null;
  }
}
```